# What could possibly cause the "border" attribute of a CSS id link to be completely ignored?

Tags: html, css

I have inherited a very large CSS file, and I added a specific `id` as follows:

```
#specialLink a, #specialLink a:link, #specialLink a:active, #specialLink a:visited
{
    border:solid 1px #000000; 
    background-color:#CC0000;
}
```

However, when I use it in a link, as in `<a id="specialLink" href="whatever.htm">Test Link</a>`, it completely ignores the `border` attribute above, but respects the `background-color` attribute.

I was led to believe that an `id` tag in CSS has ultimate priority, so what could be causing the `border` attribute to be completely ignored?

Comment: `id` doesn't necessarily give ultimate priority. Does it work if you add `!important`?

Comment: Use a css style inspector (firebug, chrome) to see if there's any overriden declaration on the border declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect. You have:

```
#specialLink a {}
```

This will match anchor elements that are *descendents* of an element with the ID `#specialLink`:

```
<div id="specialLink">
    <a href="#">Anchor</a>
</div>
```

What you want is:

```
a#specialLink {}
```

So that the selector will match:

```
<a href="#" id="specialLink">Anchor</a>
```

Comment: Specifying a#specialLink is redundant since #specialLink is unique.

Comment: Right, `#specialLink` will suffice as well. I just wanted to make it clearer where the error was in the selector.

Comment: That worked!  However, I had to specifically use `a#specialLink {}`.  `#specialLink` did NOT work.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @Programmer: my guess is the anchor is inheriting styles from something else, and the specificity or "weight" of those styles is higher than `#specialLink` but less than `a#specialLink`.

Answer (score 0):

`#specialLink a` refers to an `A` tag inside a wrapping element with an ID of "specialLink".

To style the link you need to use `#specialLink` by itself since it already has a unique ID.

```
#specialLink {
   ...
}
```